# How to push from tableview to tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CI= @"GenusNameCell";

    GenusNameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CI];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[GenusNameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                    reuseIdentifier:@"GenusNameCell"];

        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    int row = [indexPath row];

    cell.GenusNameLabel.text = [genusName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.GenusCommonNameLabel.text = _genusCommonName[row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    SpeciesViewController *Species = [[SpeciesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SpeciesViewController" bundle:nil];
    if ([[genusName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Abelia"]) {
        Species.SpeciesInt = 0; 
        [Species setTitle:[genusName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

I have 2 tableviews to connect but I don't know if this is the right code to do it with. It runs then when i click a cell it crashes. Can someone help me?

Comment: Then why would you include this code, and not the code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:...`?

Comment: Have you implemented - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 
 SpeciesViewController *Species = [[SpeciesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SpeciesViewController" bundle:nil];
 
 if ([[genusName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Abelia"])
 {
 Species.SpeciesInt = 0;
 [Species setTitle:[genusName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 }

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I submitted my edit (I thought) before any edit had taken place — thanks for the rollback.

Comment: @user3228210 Alright, now what does the crash report say?

Answer (score 1):

When you are selecting the cell, a new VC is created, but it is never presented. Use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Species animated:YES];
```

to present it.

You can also Ctrl-drag from cell in the first VC to the second VC (in Storyboard) and use this code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"nameOfYourSegue"]) {
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[SpeciesViewController class]]) {
            SpeciesViewController *Species = (SpeciesViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
         Species.SpeciesInt = 0; 
        [Species setTitle:[genusName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
}
```

Remember to set the segueIdentifier in the storyboard!

Comment: I have the top part of the code but the prepareForSegue method do I put that in the cellForRowAtIndexPath or the didSelectRowAtIndex?

Comment: prepareForSegue is automatically called before a segue is performed, so you just put it in your implementation file like any other method. What error messages do you get when the application crashes?

Comment: I put the prepareForSegue method in. It works without crashing but when I click a cell it goes to the next tableview and loads 1 of the arrays but it loads the same array for every cell i press even though I have 3 different arrays

Comment: I also can't put the [self.navigationController pushViewController:Species animated:YES]; without the declaration of the Species

Comment: Can you post the complete code you have now? Btw, the  `[self.navigationController pushViewController:Species animated:YES];` is supposed to be inserted into didSelectRowAtIndexPath after you create the SpeciesViewController. Note that you have to chose between either this approach OR using a storyboard segue.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"GenusNameCell";
    
    GenusNameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[GenusNameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
  reuseIdentifier:@"GenusNameCell"];
        
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }
    cell.GenusNameLabel.text = [genusName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

Comment: That code looks fine (when getting data from one array), but why do you have multiple arrays for different cells? Usually you would have one array with an object for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a storyboard or nibs?

If you are using storyboard you need to implement prepareForSegue, whereas if you are using nibs then you need to push the new view controller onto the stack in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @user3228210 I can't add a comment to the above as I don't have a reputation of 50, so hopefully you will see this. Without seeing how your storyboard, and model is set up it can be hard to tell you exactly what it wrong.  Are you able to provide a link to a zipped version of your project, and I will take a look?